# Migration from HDP non-secure cluster to CDP secure cluster

Tags: migration, hdfs, cloudera, hdp, cloudera-cdp

We are running a migration of HDFS data from an **HDP non-sercure** cluster to **CDP secure** cluster, when I read the Cloudera documentation, they are mentioning "distcp" as a tool to handle the migration, but also they mention only from **HDP secure** cluster to **CDP secure/non-secure** cluster which is not my case.

I have few questions :

- Should I secure the exiting cluster first and then use distcp ?
- or is it okay if I use distcp without security checks ?
- from you're experiences how can I handle such a situation ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From my experience you will have to run the distcp from the CDP secure cluster, with a valid kerberos ticket, and with the following parameter :

```
ipc.client.fallback-to-simple-auth-allowed=true
```

Full example :

```
hadoop distcp \
   -D ipc.client.fallback-to-simple-auth-allowed=true \ 
   hdfs://<hdp_namenode>:8020/<dir> \ 
   hdfs://<cdp_namenode>:8020/<dir>
```